# Arduino won't read the buttons

Tags: c, arduino

This program is intended to count the number of button1 presses and then break out of the loop with the button2 press.  The button2 is like an enter key.

If I run what is inside the do while statement by itself without the do while it will count up each button push.  I used this to verify that I have constructed my circuit correctly.  but for some unknown reason if I put the same code into a do while or just a while then it does not read the pins.  It will loop inside the do while but never exit to that done statement at the end.  If I start the arduino as I press down either of the two buttons then it will register that a button is being pressed, but as soon as I let go then it will do nothing again.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

My code

```
int ledpin = 11;
int button1pin = 7;
int button2pin = 2;
int button1counter = 0;
int button1state = 0;
int lastButton1state = 0;
int button2state = 0;
int lastButton2state = 0;
int button2counter = 0;

void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(button1pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2pin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {
  button1state = digitalRead(button1pin);
  button2state = digitalRead(button2pin);
   do  {   
    if (button1state != lastButton1state) {
     if (button1state == HIGH) {
       button1counter++;
       Serial.print("number of button 1 pushes: ");
       Serial.println(button1counter);
       }
       lastButton1state = button1state;
     }
   } while(button2state == LOW);



  Serial.println("done");


}
```

Thanks I changed it and of course your right. However, I can't quite understand why your right. Let me comment the code with my understanding and please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
void setup() {                

  pinMode(button1pin, INPUT);//tells comp to make button 1 input
  pinMode(button2pin, INPUT);//tells comp to make button 2 input
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {
  button1state = digitalRead(button1pin);//tells comp to begin reading pin?  but for how long?
  button2state = digitalRead(button2pin);
   do  {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read your button state outside of your while loop, so your button1state and button2state are never updated, that is why you enter in an infinite loop just do that little change:

```
void loop() {
    do  {
        button1state = digitalRead(button1pin);
        button2state = digitalRead(button2pin);

        if (button1state != lastButton1state) {
            if (button1state == HIGH) {
               button1counter++;
               Serial.print("number of button 1 pushes: ");
               Serial.println(button1counter);
            }
            lastButton1state = button1state;
        }
   } while(button2state == LOW);

  Serial.println("done");


}
```

Comment: Thanks I changed it and of course your right.  However, I can't quite understand why your right.  Let me comment the code with my understanding and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Chad edit your question, don't delete the current content, just add the following code and text to your question, which you wanted to comment here.